# login with facebook on cordova app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I'm trying to make the login in my mobile application using cordova.
I don't want to use the facebook plugin to connect via my android application and instead of that I'm using the login to facebook via my server with artdarek Laravel package.
 in my application in my app.js I have done this:

```
function login_fb(){
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "my_server/facebook",
       data: {

            },
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);

       },
       error : function(res){

       console.log('Ajax error authentification.');
       }
     });

 }
```

in my server I have done this:

```
public function loginWithFacebook() {
      $user = Session::get('connected_user');
    if (!isset($user)) {
           // get data from input
        $code = Input::get('code');

      // get fb service
        $fb = OAuth::consumer('Facebook');

        // check if code is valid
        // if code is provided get user data and sign in

if (!empty($code)) {
    // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken($code);
        $result = json_decode($fb->request('/me'), true);
        $user_obj = User::where('email', '=', $user_email)->first();
           // Log the user in
        Sentry::login($user_obj, false);
         //dd($result);
                return 'ok';

    }
       // if not ask for permission first
    else {
             $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();
             Redirect::to((string) $url);
                 //  header("Location:".$url);
                 //  die();
        }
    } else {
        return 'not_ok';
        return Redirect::route('apilogin');
    }
}
```

I can't display the facebook login interface on my mobile application although I got the url of this page.
I get the error ajax message on my log console.
Is there any solution how to use facebook login in an cordova android application?

Comment: does the code work in your pc?

Comment: @Daniel Cheung it works on my pc if I put `return Redirect::to((string) $url);`